# C# wpf EF6 Фильтр по дате

Tags: c#, entity-framework

ситуация такая: 
У меня есть таблица, занесённая в datagrid через Entity Framework, в этой таблице есть столбец Даты
Затем у меня есть рядом панелька, где я могу фильтровать по различным критериям, и вот мне нужно отфильтровать по дате, то есть я в datetimepicker ввожу дату, нажимаю применить и в таблице ток по этой дате записи отображаются, и код я написал верный, но у меня подозрение, что форматы конфликтуют, у меня таблички сделаны в SQL Server и там у столбца дата тип данных date, но почему то в самой таблице он показывает полный формат (дд,мм,гг,чч,мм,сс АМ)

**Нужно сделать так, чтобы и у столбца даты в таблице и у datetimepickerа были одинаковые форматы для того, чтобы он смог отфильтровать по совпадениям, помогите пожалуйста решить этот вопрос**

Код фильтрации по дате:

```
var query =
        from schedules in dataEntities.Schedules
        where schedules.FlightNumber == numFlightText.Text
        orderby schedules.Date
        select new { schedules.Date, schedules.Time, schedules.AircraftID, schedules.RouteID, schedules.EconomyPrice, schedules.Confirmed, schedules.FlightNumber };
        dataGridTable.ItemsSource = query.ToList();

        // Фильтруем по дате
        dataGridTable.ItemsSource = query.Where(a => a.Date == flightDatePicker.SelectedDate).ToList();
```

Дата в SQL Server:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дата в программе:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В чем конкретно проблема? Покажите ваши Entity, ваш контекст и код фильтрации.

Comment: @tym32167 Конкретно проблема в том, что когда я ввел дату и нажал применить фильтр, он не фильтрует, а показывает 0 записей, а в коде я просто ItemSource дата грида заполняю с условием Where введенной даты

Comment: Какая конкретно дата уходит в фильтрацию? Какие даты у вас в БД лежат? Отладчиком смотрели? Где код фильтрации?

Comment: @tym32167 прикрепил код фильтрации

Comment: @tym32167 дата уходит в фильтрацию в формате 23.03.2020 00:00:00

Comment: 1) код покажите текстом, а не картинкой 2) окей, то есть дата едет в бд верная. Так в чем проблема тогда?

Comment: @tym32167 вот я и не могу понять в чём проблема, не показывает записи с выбранной датой, а просто пустая таблица идёт, мол с такой датой не найдено

Код приложил выше

Comment: @tym32167 Сейчас покажу код, как выглядят даты в SQL Server и как они выглядят, когда я их вывожу в таблицу программы

Comment: У вас даты содержат временную зону?

Comment: @tym32167 прикрепил скрины дат

Comment: Если вы запустите код `var date = new DateTime(какая то дата); dataEntities.Schedules.Where(x=>x.Date == date).ToList();` - он вернет что то из базы?

Comment: я просто предполагаю, что у вас может быть проблема с временными зонами. Если у вас, например, в БД хранятся в UTC, а передаете вы в локальном времени, то из за временных зон даты могут не совпадать. Чтобы такого избежать, дату и время обычно хранят в UTC , и в запросы передают время в UTC

Comment: @tym32167 да, вытащил дату, которая действительно есть

Comment: @tym32167 Только он почему то любую дату вытаскивает

Comment: @tym32167 А нет, всё в порядке, да, работает, дата, которая есть в БД, он вытаскивает, а если введу дату, которой нет, то возвращает 0

Comment: Ну то есть либо вы фильтруете так, что у вас нет расписаний , совпадающих с вашим фильтром. Либо вы дату передаёте не в той зоне временной, в которой храните в бд.

Comment: @tym32167 В этом то и проблема, я вот не знаю, как заставить компонент DateTimePicker в нужном для бд формате передавать

Comment: `var date = new DateTime(flightDatePicker.SelectedDate.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Unspecified).Date;` ? или `var date = new DateTime(flightDatePicker.SelectedDate.Ticks, DateTimeKind.UTC).Date;`?

Comment: @tym32167 не находит метод Ticks

Comment: Вот у этого `flightDatePicker.SelectedDate` какой тип?

Comment: Это просто компонент, размещенный на форме, DateTimePicker

Comment: @tym32167 вернее просто DatePicker

Comment: Я не про компонент спросил, а про конкретное поле

Comment: @tym32167 Ну, у него и стоит тип DatePicker, я тыкаю на этот компонент, выбираю из календаря дату и применяю фильтр

Comment: `SelectedDate` не может иметь тип DateTimePicker

Comment: @tym32167 Вот такой: DateTime?

Comment: `var date = new DateTime(flightDatePicker.SelectedDate.Value.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Unspecified).Date;` ?

Comment: @tym32167 Помоглоооо!!! Спасибо вам огромное, очень помогли, всё фильтруется

Comment: @tym32167 ответом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я просто предполагаю, что у вас может быть проблема с временными зонами. Если у вас, например, в БД хранятся в UTC, а передаете вы в локальном времени, то из за временных зон даты могут не совпадать. Попробуйте

```
var date = new DateTime(flightDatePicker.SelectedDate.Value.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Unspecified).Date;
```